# Date with effective date in single row - wanted to select in multiple row

Tags: oracle

I have the below data in a table.

I am trying to build a result with 3 row for the given row of data.

[image]

Since the exception start and end date are following between actual start and end date

I am looking for a query that return the below result in select query, if this even possible.

[image]

It is also not necessary that exception start and end date should be within the actual start and end date. They can even overlap or completely outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you want to select three intervals

- from actual start date to exception start (exclusive)
- from exception start to exception end
- from exception end (exclusive) to actual end

This is done straight with the SELECT below.

Note, that you need to add or subtract one day for the exclusive boundaries

```
select PRODUCT, LOCATION,              ACT_START_D,   EXP_START_D -1  ACT_END_D from tab union all
select PRODUCT, LOCATION, EXP_START_D  ACT_START_D,   EXP_END_D       ACT_END_D from tab union all
select PRODUCT, LOCATION, EXP_END_D +1 ACT_START_D,                   ACT_END_D from tab
order by 1,2,3
;
```

returns

```
P L ACT_START_D         ACT_END_D          
- - ------------------- -------------------
C L 10.12.2012 00:00:00 09.03.2020 00:00:00
C L 10.03.2020 00:00:00 10.04.2020 00:00:00
C L 11.04.2020 00:00:00 10.12.2024 00:00:00
```

**You must describe the expected logic for the outside and overlapping exception and adjust the query.**